# CKEditor plugin not disabled

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I was initially using a plugin by the name of pasterFromWord for CkEditor but when I deleted the folder from under '/plugins' and deleted all the code in my 'config.js' file, the function of the plugin is still active i.e when I copy text from a word file and paste it, it automatically deletes the content!

Someone who may have come across this issue earlier, could you please guide me? Is it a caching issue, because I cleaned my server directory and my browser cache too... and it still works. Let me know if you need more input from my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the plugin is active checking `CKEDITOR.instances.editor_name.plugins` in the browsers console.

Maybe you build CKEditor with that plugin. Then the plugin will be included in the `ckeditor.js` file. You can use `config.removePlugins` config option to be sure it will not be loaded (but removing it from the config should work too).

What is more likely, it is not a `pasterFromWord` plugin who remove your content, but the [Advance Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf). It removes all elements you can not edit in the editor. Try to use `config.allowedContent = true;` option to disable Advance Content Filter and check if it helps. If it do, set ACF rules so it will filter your data as you need (if you leave ACF disabled you will get a lot of unneeded content in the editor).